# Type based on another type

Tags: typescript

I have object with keys `type` and `playground`. So I want `payload` type to be based on `type` type

```
enum Type {
    TYPE_A,
    TYPE_B,
    UNKNOWN,
}

interface PayloadA {
    name: string;
}

interface PayloadB {
    value: number;
}

type Entity = { type: Type.TYPE_A; payload: PayloadA } | { type: Type.TYPE_B; payload: PayloadB } | { type: Type.UNKNOWN; payload: {} };

function getType(typename: string): Type {
    switch (typename) {
        case 'a':
            return Type.TYPE_A;
        case 'b':
            return Type.TYPE_B;
        default:
            return Type.UNKNOWN;
    }
}

function getPayload(typename: string): Entity['payload'] {
    switch (typename) {
        case 'a':
            return { name: '' };
        case 'b':
            return { value: 0 };
        default:
            return {};
    }
}

const typename = 'a';

const entity: Entity = {
    type: getType(typename),
    payload: getPayload(typename),
};
```

Throws error here

`const entity: Entity = {`

`Type 'Type' is not assignable to type 'Type.UNKNOWN'`

Could you help me? I have no idea how to write correct types

[TypeScript code playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2FA3gKCp2BNACgUQH0BBAGgyxjyICFysoBVAOQGlmB5AdWfIF80aAJYgALsABOAMwCGAY2S4ZcADYB7GQBNiqCphAyIwAFxQAzqIkiA5gG40A4WMmyFUJao2aauhgDcZFTATKHAIACNJe0dRRGR8MSFYqABeVChYpFN4JAA6KgISWygEZXUtUw9y7Sg%20KAAfdMyQnOB86kIaYtLPCvcyrx86xpQMuOy43JZ2bmZugb6UOr57NCkwEDlRITUQKGtgUVaACmaDI1MLKxBrAEoJpF8sMwB3JLkACyhTuPPgW6eDEwchkZmQAHIZODjHogQwJIcwBI9q12oViPY4cDQRDwtDYVioAjREiUZMCrRMVjNMBZGAVKIYYT4YjkbBJtNODwqZgBI51pttrt9ocql4fkg-pdLDZ7lAEttYgBtcE9arggC6gPMb1En2%20Z0M-21DBBYKgkPxzKwxNJ6SlFvBtR5QLNuKt1qJrL2owCQRCAAZnQSsDS6QymZ7bWyli6%20YI5LsLGNJUbUhaoatEyBk6BFXBTAqknB0%20gGM1TAcjnEJaAjbd6Fg1V5K6KFppa38Gw5bEA)

Comment: Alternatively you could merge the 2 methods into one `getEntity`.

Comment: good advice) thx